# Differences between PTs in DXA

Tags: dxa, templating

I found that two page templates are similar in DXA - Home Page and Section Page. Their fields in [Page Template Metadata] have the same values - configured to contain only header and footer and the same page view name.
Is there any difference between those two PTs?

Answer (score 4):

They do appear to have the same metadata and includes, so in the default dxa setup, they are the same.

However, separating the home page and section pages in two different templates can be useful, for example if you wish to apply a different layout to the homepage, or add an extra include to the section pages.

If all pages would use the same page template, this wouldn't be possible (or you would need to change and republish a number of pages).